Где хранятся настройки гаммы?
Каждый раз после переустановки винды мучаюсь с настройками гаммы. Думал, они сохраняются в icc профиле, но, похоже, что нет. Без настроек гаммы монитор выдает ужасную картинку. Подскажите, можно ли выудить из работающей винды файлик с настройками гаммы, чтобы скармливать его после переустановки и получать ту же картинку?

гамм - две штуки, вы про какую из них? гамма есть на самом мониторе, и хранится собственно в мониторе; и гамма есть в драйвере на видеокарту - и хранится собственно в драйвере видеокарты

я про ту, которая сохраняет в винде после использования встроенного приложения "Калиьровка цветов монитора". После переустановки системы несмотря на вытащенный icc файл пришлось снова таскать в ней ползунок гаммы и прям того же результата что до переустановки добиться не удалось.

так, наверное нужен ответ, сюда всё не влезет, и не удобно

Что то сбивает настройки драйвера видеокарты.
Найдите новую [последнюю] версию драйвера именно под вин-11, скачайте её. Искать/качать драйвер нужно на сайте производителя видеокарт.
Удалите все драйверы на видеокарты, если они есть. А они могут быть.
Панель управления > Диспетчер устройств > Вид > Показать скрытые устройства > Видеоадаптеры > [Возможно] много всяких установленных драйверов - все на удаление. В вин-7-10 это работает, как это работает в вин-11 - не знаю. Погуглите, если оно не так в вин-11.
После того как удалили всё не нужное, перезагрузитесь - ставьте новый [последний] драйвер. Попытайтесь не ставить его так, что бы он "подсасывал" обновления. Т.е. запретите обновления, если это возможно. Если вы понимаете что делаете - полазьте по драйверу и посмотрите его настройки точнее. Может быть найдётся что-то полезное. Обновления бывают закопаны во многих местах. Если нашли один пункт "про обновления" - это не значит что вы нашли все пункты "про обновления". Ищите облазьте всю панельку настроек на видеокарту.
Отключите все профили видеокарты. Здесь под профилем имеется ввиду не icc-профиль. Профиль видеокарты - это глобальные сохранённые настройки на видеокарту.
Найдите драйвер на монитор и его тоже поставьте [впрочем, обычно это "заглушка", но не всегда]. Естественно на сайте-производителе. В этом драйвере на монитор icc-профиль и есть.
После этого найдите и скачайте стандартные [широкоизвестные] бенчмарки на видеокарты. Погоняйте вашу видеокарту, без фанатизма. Но какое то время - это нужно.
После этого обычно всё всегда работает, при условии если всё исправно, конечно же. Пробуйте. Если не заработает, тогда будем "копать" дальше.
П.С. Проанализируйте ПО, впрочем наверное вы не сможете. Существует ли такое ПО, которое меняет настройки видеокарты? Такое бывает. Вопрос - стоит ли у вас такое ПО?
П.П.С. Стандартная фиксация проблемы заключается в следующем - задайте себе вопрос. Что вы делали, перед тем как вылазит проблема? Вот что конкретно вы запускаете, ровно перед тем как всё "падает"? Что предшествует проблеме?
П.П.П.С. Калибровщиком вёнды наверное пользоваться не нужно. Он отчасти, почти всегда "программный". А вам нужен - железный. Завязанный на видеокарту и драйвер. Т.е. калибровать цвет нужно через программку от производителя видеокарты. Они [такие программки-калибровщики] обычно есть. Суть: виндавозный калибровщик цвета используется в самую последнюю очередь, это когда совсем выхода нет. И если вы им пользуетесь - вы сразу резко теряете производительность графических компонентов вёнды. Потому что виндавозный калибровщик - работает поверх всего. И работает он программно, т.е. каждый пиксел пересчитывается не железом, а вёндой [на процессоре]. И это очень очень плохо.
